# Does $\exists x(Bx)$, where $B$ = blue, mean "there is something (but not everything) that is blue" or "at least one thing is blue"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Does $\exists x(Bx)$ mean that

1. "something is blue but not everything"

   or
2. "something is blue perhaps everything

Comment: The second one: "There is something that is Blue". It holds also in a "universe of discourse" with a single object that is blue.

Comment: both says "there is something that Is blue", so..?

Comment: "something is blue but not everything" suggests there is something else which is not blue. $\exists x(Bx)$ does not suggest that

Comment: @Robert : OP’s wording of the first one asserts that there also exists something which is not blue, so they are not equivalent as written

Comment: To give another example, consider the statement $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} : n > 0$. This claim is true, since there does indeed exist a natural number greater than $0$. And we are not troubled by the fact that all natural numbers satisfy this condition.

Comment: Correspndingly, there is an old convention (but no longer used) under which $\forall x (Bx)$ means: all things are blue and there is at least one thing.

Comment: why should someone use the existential quantifier meaning "all.."

Answer (score 3):

The point of quantifiers is to indicate whether there exists at least one of a certain thing or there doesn't. For the former, we use $\exists$; this says nothing of whether anything else exists. For the latter, say we want to say nothing is blue: we can either write $\neg\exists x(Bx)$, or equivalently $\forall x(\neg Bx)$. Note that the universal quantifier isn't intended to say whether anything exists, so "all things are non-blue" [is consistent with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) "come to think of it, all things are blue too, because nothing exists".